# Sorting BufferedWriter string output by distinct value in java

Tags: java, sorting, bufferedwriter

I have this function:

It gets me all the data that I want but I need to sort the output by the work time. I can't figure out how to sort the data I'm getting.

Any tips are appreciated.

```
raportBtn.setOnAction(event -> {

      Writer writer=null;
      try {
          File file = new File("C:/user/raport.txt");
          writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file));
          for(Employee emp:listOfEmployees){
              String text = emp.getName() + " " + emp.getSurname()+ " " + emp.getRoom() + " " + emp.getWorkStart() + " " + emp.getWorkEnd() + " " + emp.getWorkTime() + "\n";
              writer.write(text);
          }
      } catch (IOException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
      } finally{
          {
              try{
                  writer.flush();
              }catch(IOException e){
                  e.printStackTrace();
              }
              try{
                  writer.close();
              }catch(IOException e){
                  e.printStackTrace();
              }
          }
      }
  });
```

Comment: this is unrelated to fx, isn't it? sort the list before writing to the file, have a look at Collections.sort (you need a comparator)

Comment: It's related to javafx because the data is table view. I did the fix with collection but then it sorts also my tableView. I want only output sorted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything you need is to implement a Comparator. Let's say that you want to sort the list by age(ascending). Then:

```
import java.util.Comparator;
public class EmployeesComparator implements Comparator<Employee> {

  @Override
  public int compare(Employee o1, Employee o2) {
    return o1.age - o2.age;
  }
}
```

Then, you can use it like this:

```
Collections.sort(listOfEmployees, new EmployeesComparator());
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: It worked but it also sorts contents of my table view when I press raportBtn. Is there a way to connect the sorting only to writer.write(text) @Anastasios Moraitis?

Comment: @PawełKumanowski yes if you copy your list to a temporary list. Of course there's a better way to do that, but its the first thought I have.
`List<Employee> temp = listOfEmployees;
Collections.sort(temp, new EmployeesComparator());`